# How do i access the sql message from the error given by sequelize.js

Tags: error-handling, sequelize.js, nodejs-server

While passing a invalid ID in my Sequelize Create function, Sequlize returns a error in the following format.

`` Error at Query.run (B:\Node JS\Backend Express\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mysql\query.js:52:25) at B:\Node JS\Backend Express\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:314:28 at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) at async MySQLQueryInterface.insert (B:\Node JS\Backend Express\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-interface.js:308:21) at async model.save (B:\Node JS\Backend Express\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:2432:35) at async time_sheet.create (B:\Node JS\Backend Express\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:1344:12) at async Object.createtimesheet (B:\Node JS\Backend Express\services\Timesheet.service.js:8:13) at async createtimesheet (B:\Node JS\Backend Express\controller\timesheet.controller.js:22:18) { name: 'SequelizeDatabaseError', parent: Error: Incorrect datetime value: 'Invalid date' for column 'tsdate' at row 1 at Packet.asError (B:\Node JS\Backend Express\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packets\packet.js:728:17) at Execute.execute (B:\Node JS\Backend Express\node_modules\mysql2\lib\commands\command.js:29:26) at Connection.handlePacket (B:\Node JS\Backend Express\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:456:32) at PacketParser.onPacket (B:\Node JS\Backend Express\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:85:12) at PacketParser.executeStart (B:\Node JS\Backend Express\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packet_parser.js:75:16) at Socket.<anonymous> (B:\Node JS\Backend Express\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:92:25) at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28) at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12) at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9) at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:234:10) { code: 'ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE', errno: 1292, sqlState: '22007', sqlMessage: "Incorrect datetime value: 'Invalid date' for column 'tsdate' at row 1", sql: 'INSERT INTO `time_sheet` (`LOGINID`,`tsdate`,`checkout`,`timeid`,`daytype`) VALUES (?,?,?,DEFAULT,?);', parameters: [ 1, 'Invalid date', '2022-01-17 18:33:00', 'none' ] }, original: Error: Incorrect datetime value: 'Invalid date' for column 'tsdate' at row 1 at Packet.asError (B:\Node JS\Backend Express\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packets\packet.js:728:17) at Execute.execute (B:\Node JS\Backend Express\node_modules\mysql2\lib\commands\command.js:29:26) at Connection.handlePacket (B:\Node JS\Backend Express\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:456:32) at PacketParser.onPacket (B:\Node JS\Backend Express\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:85:12) at PacketParser.executeStart (B:\Node JS\Backend Express\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packet_parser.js:75:16) at Socket.<anonymous> (B:\Node JS\Backend Express\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:92:25) at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28) at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12) at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9) at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:234:10) { code: 'ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE', errno: 1292, sqlState: '22007', sqlMessage: "Incorrect datetime value: 'Invalid date' for column 'tsdate' at row 1", sql: 'INSERT INTO `time_sheet` (`LOGINID`,`tsdate`,`checkout`,`timeid`,`daytype`) VALUES (?,?,?,DEFAULT,?);', parameters: [ 1, 'Invalid date', '2022-01-17 18:33:00', 'none' ] }, sql: 'INSERT INTO `time_sheet` (`LOGINID`,`tsdate`,`checkout`,`timeid`,`daytype`) VALUES (?,?,?,DEFAULT,?);', parameters: [ 1, 'Invalid date', '2022-01-17 18:33:00', 'none' ] } ``

I want to reteive the line
`sqlMessage: "Incorrect datetime value: 'Invalid date' for column 'tsdate' at row 1",`

for error handling

```
async function createtimesheet (req) {
    console.log("servies");
    console.log(req);
    let error ;
     data = await time_sheet.create(req).catch(err =>{
    error = err;
         })
    
    if (error) {
    console.log("has error");
    console.log(error);  ////undefined 
    return error
    } else {
    console.log("has no error");
    return data
    }

  }
```

error.sqlMessage is also not working.
I want to log the value of  SQL message.

Comment: did you try to set a breakpoint to look at the structure of the `error`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
error.message
```

for a short error message and use

```
error.original
```

for more detailed information.